# Что нужно для того, что бы переделать язык с динамической типизацией в язык с статической типизацией?

Tags: компилятор, типизация, julia, динамическая-типизация

Много ли придётся переделывать? Вкратце, расскажите пожалуйста какие шаги нужны для этого. Например мне очень нравится язык Julia, но статическая типизация там неполноценная.

Comment: А можно чуть больше описать в вопросе? Вы хотите переделать Julia был со статической типизацией? Или вы хотите переписать весь код с Julia на язык со статической типизацией? Если первое, тогда ничего сложного - просто в описание каждой перемнной кладете её тип и проверяете во время выполнения. Если тип не совпадает, требуется обязательный кастинг типов. Кастинг - просто еще пара ключевых конструкций языка.

Comment: Переделать язык с динамической типизацией в язык с статической типизацией. Относится к языку, к компилятору.

Comment: Добавить кастинг типов и тип данных для каждый переменной. При компиляции проверять, что типы совпадают, если нет - ошибка.

Comment: ну так сделайте ответом, чего в комментарии то пишете)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По сути дела для этого необходимо добавить и реализовать несколько возможностей:

1. Добавить в структуру, которая описывает каждую переменную информацию о типе этой переменной. Это может как примитив, так и объект, интерфейс и т.д.
2. Добавить возможность кастинга одного типа переменных в другие. Пример этого из Java:

   long l = 100000;
   int i = (int) l;
3. На этипе компиляции проверять тип данных, если он не совпадает или не может быть преобразован по дереву типов, тогда ошибка.
4. Так же еще придется хранить дерево классов, если язык поддерживает ООП. Это необходимо для того, чтобы в качестве параметров могли использовать дочерние классы и наоборот. Небольшой пример из Java

   ```
   public class Animal {
       public void eat() {
           // ... 
       }
   }
   public class Cat extends Animal {
       public void eat() {
            // ... 
       }
       public void meow() {
            // ... 
       }
   }
   Cat cat = new Cat();
   Animal animal = cat;
   animal = (Animal) cat;
   ```